# I'm in Rails. How to set up a model so each element of Collage array "has_one" Work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I'm sitting here in Rails 3 and MongoDB, and am trying to relate models in a way I haven't ever done before.  I want to make a collage of work pictures, but rather than having a collage table, a slides table, a work table, and an images table, I want to have each collage be an array called "slides", where each element in "slides" is a work id.

So, a Collage is an array of work ids.

Here's what's in the database (besides the clients and work and whatnot):

```
puts 'Adding sample slide data...'
Collage.create(slides: [client.work.first.id, client.work.second.id, client.work.third.id])
puts 'Added sample slide data'
```

I want to tie the models together somehow, like collage.slide[] has_one Work, and work belongs_to collage.slide[], so I could eventually write

```
collage.slides[1].work.image
```

but I don't know what the relationship between the models should be.  collage.slides[1] is a work id, so right now the following works:

```
Work.find(collage.slides[1]).image
```

but that's miami-style programming right there.  I hope this is clear enough, sorry if it isn't.

Comment: Hi, have you checked mongoid or mongomapper? I believe both of them support active record associations.

Comment: Can works belong to more than one slide?

Answer (score 0):

`has_one` is for one-to-one relationships. That isn't what you want in this case.

If you were using mongoid, this is one design that could work for you. In it, there is a Collage class which embeds many slides.

```
class Collage
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :slides
end

class Slide
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :collage
  belongs_to :works
end

class Work
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :Slides
  field :image_url, type: String
end
```

If you don't need the helper methods on the classes just create arrays and embedded documents yourself and manipulate them using the Ruby driver as needed. Essentially these class definitions would create the following collage documents:

Collage:

```
{
  "slides": [
    {
      "works": [ work_id, work_id , ....]
    },
    {
      "works": [ work_id, work_id , ....]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No, work can't belong to more than one slide.  There will be one collage, fifteen slides, and one work for each slide...  I've started a new question about the way I think I"m going to do it now:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201263/custom-rails-mongoid-relationship-names-not-working

Comment: Actually, I'm not doing it that way any more either.