# Custom rails/mongoid relationship names not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to get custom relationship names to work in Mongo.

A "collage" is a BSON document filled with BSON fields that are Work Ids.  Here's what's in the database for "collage":

```
Collage.create(slide_one: client.work.first.id, slide_two: client.work.second.id, slide_three: client.work.third.id)
```

So, a collage is mongo record full of work Ids.  I'd like to be able to write @collage.work_one or @collage.slide_one.work_one, or @collage.slide_one.work to get to the Work I want.

Custom naming these associations is proving fruitless.  So far I've tried two things:

This is how it seems to say to do it on the mongo website, but when I set it up and call @collage.work_one.inspect I get nil. http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html (bottom of page)

collage.rb

```
has_one :work_one, class_name: 'Work', inverse_of: :slide_one
```

work.rb

```
belongs_to :slide_one, class_name: 'Collage', inverse_of: :work_one
```

@collage.work_one.inspect literally just prints out "nil"

.

.

I also tried

collage.rb

```
has_one :work_one, class_name: 'Work', as: :work_oneable
```

work.rb

```
belongs_to :work_oneable
```

But that gives me:

```
uninitialized constant WorkOneable
```

Any help or ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your class declaration is correct (the first one). However, you should use the actual objects instead of id when assigning the fields, like this:

```
Collage.create(slide_one: client.work.first, slide_two: client.work.second, slide_three: client.work.third)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't wind up doing it this way, but I'll put your response in my memory bank to use later :)